# calculate EndDate based on only weekdays

Tags: apex, controller, date

I have a function which takes input as startDate and return the endDate where endDate is Date after 100 days excluding weekends. That is only weekdays are counted and not the weekends in the 100 days calculation. Can someone help me with this logic ? This is so far what I have written

```
public Date calculateEndDate( Date startDate) {
     Map<String,Integer> week=new Map<String,Integer>();
    week.put('Monday',1);
    week.put('Tuesday',2);
    week.put('Wednesday',3);
    week.put('Thursday',4);
    week.put('Friday',5);
    week.put('Saturday',6);
    week.put('Sunday',7);
    Date endDate;
    DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(startDate, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
    String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
    Integer count=1;

    endDate=startDate;
    return null;
```

Comment: What about holidays. Are you trying to just get a difference of 100 business days?

Comment: Just the business days nothing about holidays

Comment: So if July 4 is on a Monday, it should still count towards the 100?

Comment: Yes, only exclude the weekends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add 140 days (20 weeks). In any given 20 week stretch, there will be 100 weekdays and 40 weekend days.

```
public Date calculateEndDate(Date start) { return start.addDays(140); }
```

If, for some reason, you want to get every date in between, it could look something like:

```
public class EndDateCalculator
{
    public final Date endDate;
    public final List<Date> weekdays;
    public EndDateCalculator(Date start)
    {
        Datetime pointer = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(start, Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0));
        weekdays = new List<Date>();
        while (weekdays.size() < 100)
        {
            pointer = pointer.addDays(1);
            Integer dayOfWeek = Integer.valueOf(pointer.format('u'));
            if (dayOfWeek < 6) weekdays.add(pointer.date());
        }
        endDate = weekdays[99];
    }
}
```

Comment: I also want to know the dates for the weekdays not just the end date that why i am running into problem for the logic

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Do you want to track holidays or not? How do you want to get the weekdays back?

Comment: No i do not want to track the holidays but i need the dates in between that is weekdays dates

Comment: How are you supposed to get the dates in between when your return type is `Date`?

Comment: After adding 140 days to the start date I need to get the dates between the start date and end date which are on weekdays also, they can be stores in a list or something which I have to use later in my program